# ui-sref params option with $state.href not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, directive, ui-sref

I have a state definition like this:

```
 $stateProvider.state('password', {
    url: '/password',
    templateUrl: 'password.html',
    controller: 'PasswordController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    params: {
        accountNumber: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        }
    },               
});
```

I need to reference this state with its `href` rather than using `ui-serif` directive, How can I set `params.accountNumber` inside href?

This doesn't work:

```
$state.href('password', {accountNumber: $scope.accountNumber})
```

When I change this line `url: '/password',` to ` url: '/password?accoutNumber', and remove this part

```
params: {
    accountNumber: {
        value: null,
        squash: true
    }
},
```

`$state.href` works just fine.

Comment: Why you are not using `$state.go`. It is any time better to change state with required parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to generate URL with **`$state.href`** and pass parameter...

- such parameter must be part of **`url`** definition
- declaring it just in **`params: {}`** will result in href - not containing it, **not passing** it

there is adjusted state definition:

```
  .state('password', {
    url: '/password/:accountNumber',
    templateUrl: 'password.html',
    controller: 'PasswordController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    params: {
        accountNumber: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        },
      },               
  });
```

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p5k7Y8KIJXopO5EM7Jfk?p=info)

*ORIGINAL part, related to typo*

The `$state.href()` call seems to be ok... just a state definition could be wrong:

```
$stateProvider.state('password', {
    //Url: '/password',
    url: '/password',
    ...
```

The `url` setting is case sensitive. See [state.href doc here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state):

> href(stateOrName, params, options)

Comment: Ok, no if the definition is clear, I adjusted answer and created a plunker to show how to... hope it wil help a bit